How to countifs rows with arrayformula with text input in the cell (Google Sheet)?
I am able to use the countifs formula by copy paste the formula down to the sheets but i wish the formula to work around automatically once there is text enter to the header columns.
I wish the formula to work around automatically once there is text enter to the header columns.
Example file attached. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p4tth6Uql1gc7fEH8hEy8V9dUPf4HIk_Onr8pocAzRc/edit?usp=sharing


You may try:
=byrow(D5:H20,lambda(Σ,if(counta(Σ)=0,,countifs(Σ,"*"))))


